# How to initialize an array of arrays with non-constant length?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am trying to make an array which contains 1D arrays of varying length. Due to the variation in length, I cannot use a 2D array. My code is as follows:

```
int ROW = 6;
int COL = 4;
int faceverts[6][4] = {{3,2,1,0}, {4,5,1,0}, {2,6,5,1}, {2,3,5,6}, {7,3,0,4}, {1,6,7,4}};   
int (*q)[4] = faceverts;

int main(){
    for (int i = 0; i < ROW; i++){
        for (int k = 0; k < COL; k++)
            printf("%d ", *(*(q+i)+k));
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

My goal is to be able to get rid of those `ROW` and `COL` variables, as well as not have a fixed 2D array, but rather an array of 1D arrays of varying length. I have been told that using pointers is key to doing this task, but I do not know how to do this myself.

Comment: you will need to use malloc then, and instead of int faceverts[6][4],  make it int **faceverts

Comment: Is this straight up C, no C++?

Comment: Yes, this is C only. No C++ here!

Comment: `as well as not have a fixed 2D array, but rather an array of 1D arrays of varying length`.
Vary array length is not a possible thing to achieve. Once an array has been allocated either on the stack or on the heap, you cannot vary it's allocated size, unless you reallocate entire thing + copy back in the previously stored guys

Comment: Is it possible I can use pointers to multiple 1D arrays of varying length rather than specifically an array of 1D arrays?

Comment: What you want is an array of pointers.  Those pointers will then themselves point to your arrays of varying size.

Comment: `Is it possible I can use pointers to multiple 1D arrays of varying length? `.    Arrays cannot "vary" in length once allocated either on the heap or on the stack.  You can move pointers around / reallocate.   But concept of "varying" an array length is not a thing.

Comment: Ah, thank you Christian! I don't have enough rep to say that is a useful comment... but +1 anyway!

Comment: Ilan, I guess I should clarify. When I mean varying 1D arrays, I mean multiple 1D arrays of differing lengths, not an array that is actually changing size.

Comment: Initialization in C is done with fixed sizes determined when the code is compiled.  If you need variable sizes determined at runtime, you cannot use initialization — you have to use run-time assignments in some shape or form.

Comment: "multiple 1D arrays of differing lengths, not an array that is actually changing size" --> when are these lengths known? At compile time?

Comment: I am basically just passing my function a bunch of 1D arrays of varying lengths, so I do not know when the lengths are known

Comment: If the 1D "arrays" have various lengths, how would you want code to retrieve the information on the "array" length? With a separate array of length values? Or as part of the "array" - somehow?

Comment: You can make a 2D array with varying length and you do not need to use pointers. Just change `int faceverts[6][4]` to `int faceverts[ROW][COL]`, and change `int (*q)[4]` to `int (*q)[COL]`. You will also need to change how you initialize the array because obviously you can't use a fixed length braced list when the array sizes may change at runtime. If this does not answer your question then please elaborate

Comment: MM, for me the problem with using a 2D array is that the columns will be of varying lengths, and I do not think I can account for that at runtime.

Comment: So `int faceverts[6][4]` becomes `int *faceverts[6]`.  Still where do you want code to save/retrieve the length of the 1D arrays it points too?  Those 1D arrays ares not constant (4) as you say, so where/how to save its length is another issue to solve too.

Comment: @Crunchly Do you mean that the array can simultaneously hold rows of different lengths?

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to create an array of structures.  Each structure element contains a pointer and count to  an array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
  int *a;
  size_t n;
} TwoD;

#define AN(a) (sizeof (a)/sizeof (a)[0])

int smallest[1] = { 1 };
int smaller[2] = { 2, 3 };
int small[3] = { 4, 5, 6 };
int big[4] = { 7, 8, 9, 10 };
int bigger[5] = { 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 };
int biggest[6] = { 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21 };

TwoD faceverts[6] = {
    { smallest, AN(smallest) }, { smaller, AN(smaller) }, { small, AN(small) }, 
    { big, AN(big) }, { bigger, AN(bigger) }, { biggest, AN(biggest) } };

int main(void) {
  // Let us change things a bit at run time
  int change[] = { 22,23,24,25,26,27,28 };
  faceverts[0] = (TwoD) {change, AN(change)};  // compound literal
  for (size_t row = 0; row < AN(faceverts); row++) {
    for (size_t col = 0; col < faceverts[row].n; col++) {
      printf(" %d", faceverts[row].a[col]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
 22 23 24 25 26 27 28
 2 3
 4 5 6
 7 8 9 10
 11 12 13 14 15
 16 17 18 19 20 21
```

Answer (score 0):

There is only 1D array in memory. (2D array is actually a long 1D array)

Allocate a 2D array (rows, cols)

```
int *arr;
int size;
size = width * height;
arr = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * size);
```

Access element (x, y) in the array

```
int e;
int offset;
offset = x * cols + y;
e = *(arr + offset);
```

Free the array

```
free(arr);
```

Allocate a irregular 2D array (col_0, col_2, ...., col_n-1);

```
int arr;
int size = 0;
// size = col_0 + ... + col_n-1;
arr = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * size);
```

Access element (x_row, y_col) in the array

```
int e;
int offset;
// offset = col_1 + ... + col_x-1 + y_col;
e = *(arr + offset);
```